# FCM getting A bad HTTP response code (404)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, cloud, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use fcm for my website and for that I am using this tutorial:

[FCM installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCBCudx58g&t=432s) For that in my index file I have added this code:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "mykey",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "kyochat-ea3f6",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "sender_id",
  };
//   firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(e=null) {
      console.log("Granted!"+e);
      return messaging.getToken()
          .then(function(token) {
                console.log(token);
          }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log("Error! :: "+err);
          });
  })
</script>
```

And I have created a file called: firebase-messaging-sw.js which is inside my root folder. This file is empty and I can access using my url:

```
 loclahost/abc/public/firebase-messaging-sw.js
```

This file is empty I am using my apache server to call this

But I am getting this error:

```
 Error! :: FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).
```

What is wrong in my case I searched on internet everyone is saying I need to put this file firebase-messaging-sw.js in my root.

Comment: Have you read this from the [same doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) you referenced ? "The FCM SDK is supported only in pages served over HTTPS. This is due to its use of service workers, which are available only on HTTPS sites. Need a provider? Firebase Hosting is an easy way to get free HTTPS hosting on your own domain."

Comment: I don't know about document but I figure out the solution firebase-messaging-sw.js this file needs some kind of initialisation.

Comment: @NilaySingh Did you solve this issue? I am stuck in the same issue as well